# Dagger 2, MVVM: Adding a third tab and going back and forth crashes the app

Tags: java, android, mvvm, realm, dagger

I've been playing with this [github repo](https://github.com/patloew/countries): https://github.com/patloew/countries to learn DI, mvvm, realm, and all that good stuff.  When I add a **third** tab in MainAdapter.java:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new AllCountriesFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FavoriteCountriesFragment();
            //case 2:
            //    return new FavoriteCountriesFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return res.getString(R.string.tab_title_all);
            case 1:
                return res.getString(R.string.tab_title_favorites);
            //case 2:
            //    return res.getString(R.string.tab_title_favorites);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I get an exception in BaseFragment.java:

```
protected final View setAndBindContentView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        if (viewModel == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("viewModel must already be set via injection");

java.lang.IllegalStateException: viewModel must already be set via injection
```

The third fragment doesn't have to be identical to the second, it's actually a completely new fragment.  Commenting out the viewModel in onDestroyView

```
//viewModel = null;
```

avoids the crash but strange things happen afterwards.

Any pointers on what to do to help me understand the bigger picture and fix this?  The question really is **why isn't the viewModel being injected on a tab change**.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Each subclass therefore has to call the following code in onCreateView()     `if(viewModel == null) { fragmentComponent().inject(this); }`" are you doing that?

Comment: Indeed the repo does that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I've found something else I'm looking into: a fix for fragment restoration [link](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2014/02/20/a-bug-in-and-a-fix-for-the-way-fragmentstatepageradapter-handles-fragment-restoration/).  I'm hopeful it might help and will update if/when I find a fix.  Best regards.

Comment: This is only relevant if you manipulate the fragments in the pager adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `FragmentPagerAdapter` with `FixedFragmentStatePagerAdapter` from [Adam's blog](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2014/02/20/a-bug-in-and-a-fix-for-the-way-fragmentstatepageradapter-handles-fragment-restoration/) seemed to avoid the problem `(viewModel = null)`.  However, as you correctly pointed out, `fragmentComponent().inject(this)` was **not** being called in `OnCreateView` but rather in `onCreate`.  All good now.  Thank you very much for your input.